# Nested Click Event bubbling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with a nested click event (there is a large array of images, some with children images, some without).

Onclick for all of the images (children, parent and non-parent), they should display in a diff css div, and then remove themselves if clicked again, indefinitely.

So far this code works for the parent and non-parent images, but bubbling is making the children images display the parent images instead.

If I return false to stop the bubbling before the children function, it will break the functionality for the parent and non-parent images that are further down in the array (the children are in a new popup css, not a list), but if I don't stop the bubbling, the nested click event won't run.

Anyone see a good way around this mess?

```
// Click an image, and it will change it in the demo css class panel
$('.item-button').data('status','not_clicked');
$('.item-button').click(function(event) {
    var layerID = $(this).attr('data-layer'); //these do not correspond to actual layers of nesting.
    var itemID = $(this).attr('data-item');
    var itemmulti = $(this).attr('data-multi'); //this value def works to recognize parent from other non-parent items (not children).
    var clayerID = $(this).attr('data-clayer'); 
    var citemID = $(this).attr('data-citem');   //child item 1.

    if(( $(this).data('status') == 'clicked') || itemID == 0) {
        var imageSrc = $(this).parent().find('img').attr('id');
        $(layerID).attr('src', imageSrc);
    } else  {
        $(this).data('status','clicked');
        var imageSrc = $(this).parent().find('img').attr('id');
        $(layerID).attr('src', imageSrc);

        if (itemmulti != 0) {
            //begin headache.
            document.getElementById('child-' + itemID).style.display = "inline-block";

            //this is where a separate click function for children items begins.
            $('.item-sub1').data('status','unclicked');
            $('.item-sub1').click(function(event) {

            if(( $(this).data('status') == 'click') || citemID == 0) {
                var imageSrc = $(this).parent().find('img').attr('id');
                $(selector).attr('src', imageSrc);
            } else {
                $(this).data('status','click');
                var imageSrc = $(this).parent().find('img').attr('id');
                $(clayerID).attr('src', imageSrc);
            }
            return false;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```
<img button title id alt />
<input radio id="layer-{ID}-{item.ID}-radio" name="layer-{ID}" value="{item.ID}" class="item-button" data-multi="{item.PARENT}" data-layer="{ID}" data-item="{item.ID}" />
<!-- IF item.CHILD1 != 0 -->
<div id="child-{item.ID}" style="width: 300px; position: absolute; display: none;">
    <img button here title data-layer="{item.CLAYER1}" data-item="{item.CHILD1}">
    <input radio id="layer-{item.CLAYER1}-{item.CHILD1}-radio" name="layer-{item.CLAYER1}" value="{item.CHILD1}" style="display: none;" class="item-sub1" data-clayer="{item.CLAYER1}" data-citem="{item.CHILD1}" />
```

Comment: Please post your HTML markup too.

Comment: I suspect this has nothing to do with event bubbling. I see two odd things about your code: (1) binding a click event from within another click event; (2) three different click states ("unclicked", "clicked" and "click"). Maybe someone will help debugging your code if you post a working version (or not working) on jsfiddle.

Comment: There are actually 4 clicked states, clicked, not_clicked, click and unclicked. One for each diff state and two for each click event for my sanity. I think that binding a click event within a click event is the whole problem...I'll try jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you need to do to prevent the event from bubbling up the DOM tree and preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event is to use `stopPropagation()` method.

```
$('.item-button').click(function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     // your code...
```

For more info: 
   1. [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)
   2. [javascript](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)